# What contaminant materials should be avoided for reaching ultra-high vacuum?

Tags: vacuum, evaporation, experimental-technology

This question relates to ultra-high vacuum chambers (order of ~$10^{-10}$ mbar) in experimental setups.

For this particular vacuum chamber, we have a set of ion pumps and a turbomolecular pump (pumping speed: 50L/s). Once every 12 hours we also run a TSP (Titanium Sublimation Pump). This set of different types of pumps yields a base pressure in the order of ~$10^{-10}$ mbar, each pump getting rid of different residual pressures. Ion pump for the noble gasses, TSP for chemically binding the light elements and molecules and the turbo for the heavier elements and molecules.

Still, apparently, some materials should be avoided because they cannot be pumped out properly. In particular, my advisor has warned me against evaporating antimony Sb and its oxides SbO3.

I would understand this if, because of their relatively high vapour pressures (comparable to lead, calcium and bismuth [1]), these materials would be fixed to the walls and outgas at process temperatures, but we rarely heat the contaminated surfaces to temperatures higher than 200 degrees Celsius, for which the vapour pressures are $<10^{-10}$ mbar.

Now to my question: What are the considerations for materials in UHV application and when do they become contaminants leaving you with high residual pressures? (And what could you do to solve this...?) Given that only a small amount is used of this material (no bulk pieces) for evaporation.

[1] R.E. Honig, *Vapor Pressure Data for the Solid and Liquid Elements*, RCA review **30** (1969).

Comment: Lots of lore on that - go find your resident vacuum old timer for one. Remember at $10^{-10}$ Torr/mbar, it doesn't take much of anything coming off the walls to significantly affect the pressure, whether the walls are hot or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We select materials for ultra-high vacuum (UHV) based on vapor pressures and outgassing rates. Vapor pressure defines the relative amount of contaminant that will appear at a given background pressure. For example, at $10^{-10}$ mbar total pressure, a component with a vapor pressure of $10^{-11}$ mbar can theoretically comprise 10 mol % of the background gas. Outgassing rates define the pumping speed or rate needed to sustain the background pressure in a perfectly sealed system. When the pumping rate at the given pressure is higher than the outgassing rate at the given vapor pressure, the pumps will pull the component out faster than they evaporate. This brings the system pressure below the vapor pressure. The final system pressure is a balance of matching pumping rate to outgassing rate, both as a function of pressure (with vapor pressure also a function of temperature).

Regardless of the temperature, if the total system pressure in the chamber falls below the vapor pressure for the component at that temperature, the component will evaporate (outgas). The effect is the same as taking water at 95 $^o$C and atmospheric pressure and lowering total pressure. At some lower pressure, the water will boil. So by example, if you want to reach pressure $p$ in the UHV system without ever having a certain contaminant in your background gas, you should never use a component containing that substance in the UHV system if the vapor pressure of the substance at any temperature of interest is at or higher than $p$.

A good reference for further information is the [Handbook of Vacuum Science and Technology](https://www.elsevier.com/books/handbook-of-vacuum-science-and-technology/hoffman/978-0-12-352065-4).

Comment: How do you measure such high vacuums?

Comment: @DavidWhite Search for devices to measure at UHV. Vendors selling UHV equipment provide their lists and documentation. The reference book has a chapter that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

See https://outgassing.nasa.gov/ and [https://www.amazon.com/Users-Guide-Vacuum-Technology/dp/0471270520](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471270520)

What to avoid can be very research field specific. That is, some fields need to reach UHV while tolerating materials that other fields forbid.

I once heard about a small spider crawling into a uhv apparatus before a bake. I think that did not help their vacuum.

Comment: It didn't help the spider either.